# Kubernetes Helm is interpreting the same value as true from --set but false if in values file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Helm is interpreting `--set developmentVolumeMapping=0` as true, but if I put `developmentVolumeMapping: 0` in a values file and use this then Helm sees it as false.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, with "--set" you can only use "true" and "false" for boolean parameters according to the [implementation](https://github.com/michelleN/helm/blob/2f5df091fab67262547eeadc7285c06eebd60526/cmd/helm/install.go#L289).

Please also check [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/1449).